# How to disable button on submit and enabled on ASP.NET postback complete

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to disable two ASP.NET buttons on submit, and re-enabled them on postback complete. To disable the buttons I use this code:

```
cmdFiltrar.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + cmdFiltrar.ClientID + ".disabled=true;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(cmdFiltrar, ""))
cmdExcel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + cmdExcel.ClientID + ".disabled=true;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(cmdExcel, ""))
```

And it Works. But how or in wich event can i re-enabled them? I already try on page load event, but it seems not a any have effects.

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: You should disable the buttons when your form submits from client side, once the page gets reloaded, the postback was already completed and the page has been returned already

Comment: ok. I'm using Ajax so i don't know if there is a reload or not. But in any case, where do i get the buttones back enabled? thanks!

Comment: If you are using AJAX, wouldn't there be no postback?

Comment: I have two buttons. One triggers an updatePanel (AJAX) so it fires an CallBack. The other make a full page refresh (PostBack) I need to disable both buttons while server is proccessing data and re-enabled them when the data reach the client. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not using Ajax to do a post back. You are just enabling client side scripts (`JavaScript`) to cause a full post back to the server (raise an event using `__doPostBack`) unless there's an `UpdatePanel` involved.  If there's an UpdatePanel it'll do a partial postback. Anyway, here's a solution for both cases.

Add this `JavaScript` to your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function EnableButton() {

  var btn = document.getElementById("<%= cmdFiltrar.ClientID %>");
     if (btn.disabled == true) {
       btn.disabled = false;
    }
 }
</script>
```

**If there's a full postback**

Call the above `JavaScript` in your body `onLoad` event

```
<body onload="EnableButton();">
```

**If there's a partial postback**

Call the JavaScript function in your `UpdatePanel`'s client side `onLoad` event

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact I have 2 buttons: one triggers an updatepanel CallBack. The other export a grid to excel in wich i need to do a full refresh. What i need is to disable both buttons when i click any of those, an re-enabled them when the callback or postback is finish. I try to call the function in OnLoad of the UpdatePanel, but i get an error saying my function does not existe. Any idea?

Comment: Update your question with the code you tried (both markup and C#) then I'll be able to help you.